# Change the width of the Basic Bar Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I create a Bar Chart with matplotlib with :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('ETA_PRG_P2REF_RM', 'ETA_PRG_VDES_RM', 'ETA_PRG_P3REF_RM', 'Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'Perl', 'Scala', 'Lisp')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [220010, 234690, 235100, 21220, 83410, 119770, 210990, 190430, 888994]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Usage')
plt.title('Programming language usage')
plt.show()
```

Look at the attached Image [image]

But, As you can remark the width of the plot is smal, the name of object are not clear.
Can you suggest me how to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Would you consider rotating the labels?

Comment: Ok, why not , how can I do it? thanks

Comment: Would you mind replacing the line `performance = ...` with a sample array that I can use to run your code? Just a bunch of random numbers will do fine.

Comment: performance = [220010,  234690,  235100 , 21220 , 83410 , 119770 210990 ,  190430 , 888994 ]

Comment: I have updated your question so people that look at it can run it with copy-and-paste, which is what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add tick labels with a rotation:

```
pyplot.xticks(y_pos, objects, rotation=70)
```

In addition to an angle in degrees, you can specify a string:

```
pyplot.xticks(y_pos, objects, rotation='vertical')
```

You may also want to specify a horizontal alignment, especially is using an angle like 40. The default is to use the center, which makes the labels look weird:

```
pyplot.xticks(y_pos, objects, rotation=40, ha='right')
```

See the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) for a full list of options.

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra. No prob. I made a small update that may help you.